Novel about a girl who left her community by summoning and making a contract with two spirits/demons/monsters
My mother used to read a lot of fantasy/YA novels to my younger brother off of her Kindle. I remember Discworld and The Golden Compass in particular and would occasionally listen in. I asked her about this book, but she couldn't remember it.
The protagonist was female and it was a non-modern setting. At the end, she cut ties/ran away from her community by  (? unsure if it was referred to as summoning/contracts) with two spirits/demons/monsters and set up for a sequel. Doing this was accomplished through some kind of a ritual involving bottles/containers around a waterfall. It could have come out in 2018 at the latest, because that's around the time my brother outgrew being read to, and I believe it had come out semi-recently at the time, as I searched for the book on Tumblr and found several people writing promos for it.
Things I'm not sure actually happened:

This was a prequel to a different series.
The villain was revealed to be the protagonist who went back in time OR one of the demons/spirits/monsters was her from the future.
This twist was revealed through both characters wearing a specific mask.
Catalyst for leaving/face-heel turn was a town/village/settlement burning down.
The author had a Tumblr blog.

